# Azure SQL DB daily growth alert creation

Tags: azure, performance, azure-sql-database, alert

Hi I'm using azure SQL database and I need to create a notification/alert once the daily growth of the database is over a pre-defined number. As an example I need to send an email to the DB admins once the database has grown over 1 GB within the last 24 hours. I was seeking for solutions but couldn't find a straight forward solution to be implemented using azure. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can create alerts for SQL Db using alerts and action group** **in Azure**. Below are steps you can follow to create alerts for SQL DB usage for a period of time,

1. Create a logic app as shown below,
   [image]
2. In send email action, configure recipients mail addresses to notify alerts.
3. Next **create an action group** and configure the created logic app in actions tab.
   [image]
   Creating action group, [image]
4. Once logic app selected, click on review + create.
5. Now you can **create alert for sql db** and select the created action group.
   [image]
6. In Conditions tab, select signal as Data space used.
   [image]
7. As per your requirement, **configure details as shown below**,
   [image]
8. In Actions tab, select already created action group.
   [image]
9. Once it is done, click on review + create.
10. This flow will execute whenever data used is more that 1 Gb for a selected time period.
    [image]